# Как n может быть одновременно равно и 1 и 2 и 3

Tags: javascript

Как это работает? Как а меняется вообще?

```js
const a = {
  i: 1,
  toString: function () {
    return a.i++;
  }
}

if(a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) {
  console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, хитрость в том, что "Для численного преобразования объекта используется метод valueOf, а если его нет – то toString"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сравнении объекта с примитивом происходит неявное преобразование объекта с помощью метода `valueOf()`. Если его нет, используется `toString()` [см](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-conversion).
При преобразовании возвращается текущее значение свойства `i` с пост-инкрементом, т.е. возвратив `1`, `i` становится `2`. И так далее.
Ниже пример, который дает результат как в оригинале, несмотря на измененный метод `toString` - используется `valueOf()`. Если закомментировать `valueOf()`, то результат будет другой.

```js
const a = {
    i: 1,
    toString: function () {
        return 5;
    }
    ,
    valueOf: function () {
        return a.i++;
    }
}

if (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) {
    console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо